# Como ocorre a paginação feita com PHP + AJAX?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Estava navegando pelo site a procura de um exemplo funcional de paginação com AJAX + PHP, quando encontrei [este exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/p57w5/)

Desculpem minha ignorância, mas o 'carregamento assíncrono' do AJAX causa-me dúvidas..

Porém, surgiu-me uma dúvida: No script, há um limite feito por AJAX de 6 registros a serem exibidos por páginas. Sobretudo, não existe um limite caso eu faça um `SELECT * FROM tabela`. Então, deu-se a entender que, se houverem 500 registros na tabela, todos serão carregados, mas apenas exibidos seis por página? Isso não iria atrasar o fluxo do site? digo o tempo de carregamento?

Outra dúvida: Como eu poderia trocar o array no exemplo por um `SELECT`, para poder utilizar um `mysqli_fetch_array` para buscar cada linha de registro?

Obs: Caso necessário, estarei postando o código (que é um tanto extenso) para melhor visualização.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesse exemplo, realmente o AJAX exibe os registros de 6 em 6, mas todos são carregados. Se houvessem mil registros, por exemplo, seria um problema.

Uma alternativa simples é preparar uma página php contendo um SELECT limitado à X registros. Você deve passar por parâmetro o número da paginação que será mostrada e a página retornará os registros.

O comando SQL pode ser assim (php):

```
$mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT '.$inicio.','.$limite.'');
```

O retorno dessa busca será os registros no intervalo determinado. Para saber como funciona: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp.

Você deve retornar essa query como um array para o AJAX. Você pode entender como fazer isso aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220642/pass-php-array-into-javascript-array.

Mas para a paginação funcionar, você deve calcular a variável $início.

Para calcular esse início, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
$limite = 3; // Limite de registros por paginação
$pagina = (isset($_GET['page']))? $_GET['page'] : 1; // Recebe o número da paginação por método GET
$inicio = ($limite * $pagina) - $limite; // Cálculo do início
```

Você também pode obter o número total de páginas:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tabela");
$total = $result->num_rows; // Quantidade total de registros
$numPaginas = ceil($total/$limite); // Quantidade total de páginas
```

Comment: :P o `mysql_*` já morreu, o autor cita o `mysqli_*` na pergunta. [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

Comment: Obrigado por lembrar @rray. A resposta já foi adequada para o mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

Na paginação, o SELECT usado no banco precisa utilizar `LIMIT` para informar quantos registros é pra buscar e `OFFSET` para informar quantos registros deve pular. No link que você postou não informa como é feito o SELECT, ele apenas monta um array em Javascript para usar como amostra.

---

> Outra dúvida: Como eu poderia trocar o array no exemplo por um SELECT, para poder utilizar um mysqli_fetch_array para buscar cada linha de registro?

Sua requisição ajax vai chamar um script PHP, esse script por sua vez irá buscar os dados no banco usando o método que você desejar, seja PDO, mysql, mysqli, etc.

---

Para o PHP saber quantos registros pular no SELECT, você precisa informar o número da página que o usuário quer visualizar, esse parâmetro será enviado pelo AJAX ao script PHP.

**Exemplo exibindo 10 registros por página**
A URL do ajax será "script.php?pagina=1", "script.php?pagina=2", "script.php?pagina=3", etc...

```
// No script.php:
$registrosPorPagina = 10;
$pagina             = intval($_GET['pagina']);

// Calcula o offset de acordo com o número da página
$offset             = $pagina == 1 ? 0 : ($pagina * $registrosPorPagina) - $registrosPorPagina;

// Comando SELECT dinâmico, sempre irá buscar só 10 registros de acordo com a página
// offset 0: registros 1-10
// offset 1: registros 11-20
// offset 2: registros 21-30
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela LIMIT 10 OFFSET {$offset}";
```

Comment: Sim, isso eu entendi perfeitamente. Porém, acredito que minha dúvida seja exatamente essa: em que ponto do script, ou como deve ser o script em PHP que irá informar ao AJAX o limite, para que ele busque e exiba de 10 em 10. Porque, até então, eu só consigo exibir de 10 em 10, mas buscando todos, e isso faz com que todos os registros sejam carregados.

Comment: @ThiagoBarros Alterei a resposta, agora possui a lógica para saber quais registros deve buscar